# Unable to get desired output in my program

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to `c++`.

```
  #include <iostream>
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 10;
        cout << "Enter first number \n";
        cin >> a;
        if (a < 10)
        {
            cout << "Less";
        }
    }
```

now when i enter 5 nothing happens and console exits. i think it should display "Less" But it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Please show how you execute the program.

Comment: A description should be sufficient.

Comment: Its just a practice. When i enter number 5 console exits... nothing happens...

Comment: Is it the cached program? cause i have compiled it over and over again.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? What steps do you take after compiling to execute the program?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013.And build and then use F5.

Comment: Use ctrl + F5 to make the window stay open.

Comment: Use system("pause") if you are using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using some sort of IDE and usually in IDEs they display a console box that has your output, and that console box disappears when the program is done.

It ***is*** being shown, but the console window is exiting too fast for you to see it.

What you can do is add a few lines at the end, such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 10;
    cout << "Enter first number \n";
    cin >> a;
    if (a < 10)
    {
        cout << "Less";
    }

    std::string pause;
    cin >> pause;
}
```